# Does it possible to add 'if not clicked' condition on addEventListenter in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

Suppose, I want gameplay that could increase score for click on a specific colored bubble(1). If the appeared bubble not clicked, the score will decrease or even the game will over.(2)

It's easy to use `addEventListener` 'click' event to conquer the number 1. But how I can do the 2?

Comment: You could use `setTimeout` to check if the score has changed by the time desired (if not, there hasn't been a click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the behavior of your bubbles. As mentioned by @CertainPerformance, you can use a `setTimeout`, but as you are talking about bubbles, I imagine a bubble going up to the sky, so you could also use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect when the bubble leaves the viewport, for example:

```js
var bubble = document.getElementById('bubble');

var options = {
  root: document.querySelector('#window'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0
}

var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      bubble.parentNode.removeChild(bubble);
      alert('You missed it!');
    }
  });
};

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

observer.observe(bubble);

bubble.addEventListener('click', function() {
  observer.unobserve(bubble);
  alert('Got it!');
  bubble.parentNode.removeChild(bubble);
});
```

```css
#window {
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

#bubble {
  animation: fly 5s normal;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px; 
}

@keyframes fly {
  from {
    top: 250px;
  }
  to {
    top: -100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="window">
  <div id="bubble"></div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the Intersection Observer API is not supported by Internet Explorer and you will need a [polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill) for the unsupported browsers.